# Powershell Oracle ODBC Producing Inconsistent Results

Tags: oracle, powershell, odbc

I have a powershell script that queries an ODBC connection to an Oracle Database using the 12.01.00.02 version of the Oracle ODBC Driver.

We recently upgraded the Oracle server to version 12.1.0.2.0.1077237 and ever since we are seeing inconsistent results being returned from the following Powershell script.

```
Param (
[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[string]$year,
[string]$added_days = 0,
[string]$run_courses = $false,
[string]$run_enrollments = $false
)

$conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "dsn=dsnName;PWD=dsnPWD"
$conn.open()

$enrollments_query = "select 
    stu.student_number ""Email"",
    CONCAT(sch.ABBREVIATION,
      CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cou.COURSE_NAME, '/', '-'), '&', ''), ',', ''), 'ATTENDANCE ', ''), ' ', ''), ':', ''),
        CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(sec.EXPRESSION, '(', ''), ')', ''),
          CONCAT(sec.SECTION_NUMBER,
            CONCAT('-','" + $year + "'))))) as ""Class""
    from students stu
    join cc on stu.ID = cc.STUDENTID
    join sections sec ON cc.SECTIONID = sec.ID
    join courses cou ON sec.COURSE_NUMBER = cou.COURSE_NUMBER
    join schools sch ON sec.SCHOOLID = sch.SCHOOL_NUMBER
    join teachers tea ON tea.ID = sec.TEACHER
    where 
    sec.TERMID IN 
      (select ID from SCHEDULETERMS term
    where CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN term.FIRSTDAY - " + $added_days + " and term.LASTDAY + " + $added_days  + " and term.SCHOOLID = sec.SCHOOLID )"

$enrollments_cmd = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($enrollments_query,$conn)
$enrollments_cmd.CommandTimeout = 300000
$enrollments_ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$enrollments_da = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter($enrollments_cmd)
$enrollments_da.fill($enrollments_ds)

$enrollments_ds.Tables[0] | out-gridview

$enrollments_table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
$enrollments_col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Email,([string])
$enrollments_col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Class,([string])
$enrollments_table.columns.add($enrollments_col1)
$enrollments_table.columns.add($enrollments_col2)

#loop through each row in database results and add each row to the powershell data table

foreach ($resRow in $enrollments_ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{ 
    $row = $enrollments_table.NewRow()
    $row.Email = $resRow[0]
    $row.Class = $resRow[1]
    $enrollments_table.rows.add($row)
}

$enrollments_table | export-csv ("C:\windows\temp\td_enrollments.csv") -NoTypeInformation
```

It is returning the correct **number** of rows each time, but the content in the data is inconsistent in each execution and does not match data that is returned using the same query being run via an ODBC client.

Can anyone point me toward what might be causing the problem?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe how the data is inconsistent?  We don't have your data, your table definitions, or your results so it's hard to guess.

Comment: The data returns approx 51k rows, it is two columns, email and classname.  It should show every student enrolled in every course.  In looking at the data and singling out a specific classname, there should be 32 results (students) from that class (which is what my ODBC client returns correctly).  Sometimes I receive 4 records, sometimes 11, sometimes 15, and rarely all 32, but it is never consistent, and mostly always not containing the correct data number of records for that specific classname.

Comment: But you said that the number of rows being returned is correct.  Are you seeing classes with more rows than you expect?  Going out on a limb, your query does not have an `order by` clause so there is no guarantee that all rows for a single class will be returned together.  Is it possible that the issue is that you have "clumps" of rows for a single class scattered throughout the result set and when you are manually looking you aren't exhaustively searching all 51,000 rows?

Comment: The total number of rows is correct, the rows I am looking for specifically is not.  I have checked them both via looking at the CSV output and also using the out-gridview cmdlet to inspect the data and the specific data I am looking for isn't there unfortunately.

Comment: If the number of rows is right and some classes have too few rows, do other classes have too many rows?

Comment: Adding an order by clause is now producing consistent data each time.  I'm still a little confused as to why, but it is producing consistent data every time now.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `ORDER BY` on this query. Without an `ORDER BY` the database is free to return the rows in any order it cares to, and because the correct *number* of rows is being returned I suspect that the results are there but are being returned out of the order you expect. If I'm interpreting your question correctly it appears that you want to have the results ordered by `CLASS` and `EMAIL`; since the generation of the `CLASS` result is complex I suggest that you use the field-number ordering method, so in this case your query would become

```
$enrollments_query =
  "select stu.student_number ""Email"",
          CONCAT(sch.ABBREVIATION,
            CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cou.COURSE_NAME, '/', '-'), '&', ''), ',', ''), 'ATTENDANCE ', ''), ' ', ''), ':', ''),
            CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(sec.EXPRESSION, '(', ''), ')', ''),
            CONCAT(sec.SECTION_NUMBER,
            CONCAT('-','" + $year + "'))))) as ""Class""
     from students stu
     join cc on stu.ID = cc.STUDENTID
     join sections sec ON cc.SECTIONID = sec.ID
     join courses cou ON sec.COURSE_NUMBER = cou.COURSE_NUMBER
     join schools sch ON sec.SCHOOLID = sch.SCHOOL_NUMBER
     join teachers tea ON tea.ID = sec.TEACHER
     where sec.TERMID IN (select ID
                            from SCHEDULETERMS term
                            where CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN term.FIRSTDAY - " + $added_days +
                                                 " and term.LASTDAY + " + $added_days  + " and 
                                  term.SCHOOLID = sec.SCHOOLID )
     ORDER BY 2, 1"
```

That being said, it's entirely possible that a new version of the ODBC driver might have introduced a new and exciting bug. If the above doesn't change the results you're getting try uninstalling the new driver and reinstalling the old driver.

Best of luck.

Comment: Adding the order by clause has returned consistent data upon multiple runs of the script.